# Facebook PHP SDK into database will parmanent?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am just using facebook sdk to provide user to login to our website. After user login from facebook, their data will be saved into our database, especially their email.

Their email address in our database is what will be the identity for their profile, such as their shoping cart, their activity and etc.

My question now is, what if someday this user change their email address from facebook, and they still login with facebook to our website.

Automatically, if this happen, then their identity in our database won't be match?

Can anyone please give me how is the best practice for this, please?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to store both the email and the FB User's id. The user's FB profile then will remain connected to your app regardless of email. They'd still be using the old email to login to your website.

Also, I recommend not using the email as a primary key so that users have the ability to change it. Using some sort of auto-incrementing id would be a better option.

Lastly, (unless you need non-FB users to be able to sign up) using FB's login instead of using your own will effectively make it irrelevant what your users' email address is for authentication purposes, and you'll always be able to get the latest one from the API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation.